# Pandas - Reiterating rows through csv

Tags: python, pandas, canvas-lms

Obligatory warning - new to Python and Pandas.

I have a .csv file containing information that I'd like to run through [CanvasAPI](https://github.com/ucfopen/canvasapi) to grab user names. The .csv layout is:

```
     Name  user_id
0  Name_1     7454
1  Name_2     7075
2  Name_3     7377
3  Name_4     7259
4  Name_5     7294
5  Name_6     7491
```

I can process individual cells through the get_user function with no difficulty, as below:

```
from canvasapi import Canvas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Test2.csv")

user = df['user_id'][0]

print(canvas.get_user(user))
```

With an output of:

```
Name_1 (7454)
```

However, I'm utterly stumped on how to reiterate over rows in Pandas for similar pulls. My first code attempt is:

```
users = df['user_id'][0:5]

def user_id():
    for user in users:
        print(user)

print(canvas.get_user(user_id()))
```

Which generates the following error:

```
7454
7075
7377
7259
7294
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\util.py", line 116, in obj_or_id
    return int(parameter)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\2021523-18696-123dxol.cjwo", line 39, in <module>
    print(canvas.get_user(user_id()))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\canvas.py", line 1221, in get_user
    user_id = obj_or_id(user, "user", (User,))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\util.py", line 133, in obj_or_id
    raise TypeError(message)
TypeError: Parameter user must be of type User or int.
```

In trying to reiterate a second way:

```
print(canvas.get_user(df['user_id'][0:5]))
```

I run into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\2021523-18696-gmkiri.t4uur", line 49, in <module>
    print(canvas.get_user(df['user_id'][0:5]))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\canvas.py", line 1218, in get_user
    elif user == "self":
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1442, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

And a third attempt:

```
def user_id():
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        print(f"{row[1]}\n")

user_id = pd.to_numeric(user_id())

print(canvas.get_user(user_id))
```

Yields this error:

```
7454

7075

7377

7259

7294

7491

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\util.py", line 116, in obj_or_id
    return int(parameter)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\2021523-18696-62ic5r.qihqf", line 41, in <module>
    print(canvas.get_user(user_id))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\canvas.py", line 1221, in get_user
    user_id = obj_or_id(user, "user", (User,))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\util.py", line 133, in obj_or_id
    raise TypeError(message)
TypeError: Parameter user must be of type User or int.
```

I'm officially out of ideas on how to proceed. Any ideas on what I've done wrong, and where to move in the right direction? All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the output you are looking for?

Comment: Something like the following: Name_1 (7454), Name_2 (7075), Name_3 (7377).....but I want to pull the names from the API.

Comment: Your function does not return anything (it only prints). Try list comprehension:`lst = [canvas.get_user(user) for user in df['user_id'][0:5]]`

Comment: That worked - pulled each user name and accompanying data. Many thanks for the assist!

Comment: @DanielHutchinson No problem and good luck.